# hdiutil compact failed - internal error

Tags: macos, time-machine, nas

I am trying to compact a TimeMachine sparsebundle (to reclaim space) using

```
sudo hdiutil compact /Volumes/TimeMachine/MyMac.sparsebundle
```

and the error message that I receive is:

```
hdiutil: compact failed - internal error
```

When I look in the System Log, I see the following message:

```
diskimages-helper: cannot compact filesystem because it was not unmounted cleanly.
```

I am running on a MacBook Air (13-inch, early 2014) on Mavericks and the sparsebundle is located on an Iomega StorCenter ix2-dl NAS with 2TB running RAID 1.

When I look via Finder at my Iomega NAS share, I see that it is "mounted" (with that eject icon shown next to the share name). But if I eject the drive (to dismount it), then Terminal can no longer see the Time Machine volume when I use the hdiutil command.

UPDATE: I've tried the techniques on [Garth Gillespie's blog](http://www.garth.org/archives/2011,08,27,169,fix-time-machine-sparsebundle-nas-based-backup-errors.html) and no issues were reported. I also used Disk Utility and it ran cleanly (no repairs).

Any help would be most appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Update: I was running LenovoEMC's Storage Manager in another window and had a webpage opened to the ix2-dl drive.

After closing these applications, I did a full shutdown and restarted.

This time, when I tried hdiutil compact, it worked.

Just putting this answer here for anyone who runs into a similar issue. Most of the web pages that I found during searching were related to problems with sparsebundles that used FileVault.

Answer (score 1):

Same issue here, I had to mount/unmount the sparsebundle volume before running hdiutil to compact it.

Answer (score 1):

Whilst not directly answering the question a related issue led me here, and maybe others might find this useful, but when I attempted to compact and image I got the following error:

```
hdiutil: compact failed - Function not implemented
```

It turns out that hdiutil compact function is soft-disabled when the machine is running on battery power resulting in the above error. To override this behaviour add the following argument after the image name `-batteryallowed` when calling compact.

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm a bit late to this one, but if you're stuck with this issue you may want to start by checking that the volume with your disk image on it isn't full; you need a reasonable amount of free space or a lot of disk image functions will start to fail.

Once you encounter this error, you may also need to do a repair of the volume on the disk image itself; it may not actually be damaged, but you sometimes have to do this in order to clear the "unmounted uncleanly" status. I'm not sure why this is sometimes required and sometimes not, as it also might just clear on its own.

But if you do need to do it, then in Terminal you want to run:

```
hdiutil attach -nomount /path/to/disk/image.sparsebundle
```

Once this has completed (you may need to enter a password) you'll get a listing for the contents like so:

```
/dev/disk6              GUID_partition_scheme           
/dev/disk6s1            EFI                             
/dev/disk6s2            Apple_HFS
```

You can then run a repair on the correct partition (usually the last one), like so:

```
diskutil repairVolume disk6s2
```

Once this is complete you should be able to compact the image as normal.